# how to update the cell values of excel at a regular interval [Monthly]

Tags: excel, vba

i have a worksheet having the **deposit amount** and **total amount coloumn**. I want that the total amount coloumn should update automatically every month with the

```
value = (total amount + deposit amount)
```

Do i use VBA or formula..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To refresh external data at regular time intervals:

1) Open Microsoft Excel workbook.

2) Click a cell in the external data range.

3) Click the 'Data' tab. (The 'Data' tab appears.)

4) From the 'Manage Connections' group, click the 'Refresh All' drop-down list and select 'Connection Properties'. (The 'Connection Properties' dialog box appears.)

5) From the 'Refresh control' group, select the 'Refresh every' check box and in the 'minutes' box enter the appropriate number of minutes.

6) Click 'OK'.

Try this, if it is working in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make any updates if the file is closed.  Your best bet would be to write a macro that would check the date and update the value if required.  Then simply execute this macro on file open. `Workbook_open` is the name of the macro you need to have it execute automatically when you open a workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, let me suggest you that there is a possibility to achieve what you want without macros, using NOW() function and an arrangement of formulas that would count the number of months between NOW() and the predefined date.